# RequireJS and ES6 Style Javascript Module Plugin (Specifically moment-range for moment js) How To Setup Require Config?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I want to load this plugin "moment-range" for Moment which is in ES6 Format here: https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range/blob/master/lib/moment-range.js

They do also have it in this format too, not sure what to call it: https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range/blob/1effe5852e7d9312debc6ecb6de334b605bc9fb6/lib/moment-range.js

Their install docs are here:  https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range

So I have my requirejs-config.js like this:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'moment-range': 'MyCompany_Mymodule/js/utils/moment-range'
    },
    'shim': {
        'moment-range': {
            deps: ['moment']
        }
    }
}
```

};

and JS file:

```
define([
    'moment',
    'moment-range'
    ],
    function (moment, momentrange) {
```

I have tried both versions, but the momentrange is not available inside the module (shows as undefined). I can access "moment" fine, but momentrange is undefined. (moment-range js file does show up if I look at sources under chrome).

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using this version: https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range/blob/1effe5852e7d9312debc6ecb6de334b605bc9fb6/lib/moment-range.js

I just wrapped the existing code with this:

```
define(['moment'], function(moment) {
    'use strict';

// file contents from: https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range/blob/1effe5852e7d9312debc6ecb6de334b605bc9fb6/lib/moment-range.js 
// but removed this line: const moment = require('moment');

});
```

Then when I called moment it had the range plugin added to it so I could use it like moment.range(). My requirejs-config.js code was correct.